# Can I negotiate my rent if it is a German company but they want me to relocate to another country?

Tags: germany, relocation, europe

Can I ask the German company to help me with expenses of housing to be able to move if they need me in another country in Europe?

Comment: We do not know what your company is like or what kind of policies they have. Why not ask HR and see if they have something in place?

Comment: Not enough knowledge for a full answer but generally yes, if you're in a foreign country you get something to compensate for your expenses. I would consider rent such an expense. Unless of course you move to another country permanently, in which case you would need to renegotiate your contract with completely new pay, enough to cover your living expenses in that country.

Comment: Normally, you can expect your rent overseas to be paid, plus removals, plus a per diem for the first few months. I know form experience as a freelancer that my home tax office won't let me deduct foreign rent unless I also have a home in my home country. Your company _might_ take the same attitude; e.,g not pay overseas rent if you live with parents at home, but I doubt it. You should be fine to have those costs covered. ***BUT***, why not just ask HR?

Comment: Are you relocating to another location, or is this a temporary assignment? Is it expected that you would need to keep your German home in addition to housing in the new location, or are you just moving completely?

Comment: I am moving completely

Answer (score 3):

Companies handle business trip expenses in one of the following ways :

1. The company provides the housing / ticket / food

You have nothing to do. This is legally considered tax free.

2. The company refund the expense

In this case, you should keep all justificative documents and get refunded back by your company for your expenses.

3. The company gives you a package for this expense

If you take your own car, your expenses are legally covered by 0.30€ per kilometer. 
Food can be also covered by a package based on the length of your stay. This is free of taxes, again.

And if in doubt of how the company will handle a fee, the best thing might be just to ask them.

---

In case you are moving permanently, this is different. You need to renegociate your contract with the new location, including if appliable a different pay and other benefits the company might provide for relocation (company policy here, nothing legally granted).

In all cases, if the conditions aren't favorable, you can always decline a permanent relocation offer as any other renegociation of your contract.

Comment: The way I read the question, I thought the OP was relocating to another country, not just a business trip.

Comment: You might be right, i'll make a proper edit with the case

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, you also need to check your cost of living elsewhere. For example, if you move to London you might be in for a shock.

If you ask your company what they are paying and you don’t fully agree, update your question here.